# What is the equation of the separation line for this neuron with identity activation?

Tags: machine-learning, math, artificial-neuron, activation-functions

I have a single neuron with 2 inputs, and identity activation, where `f` is activation function and `u` is output:

$u = f(w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + b) = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + b$

My guessing for the separation line equation:

$u = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + b$
$\implies x_2 = \dfrac{u - w_1x_1 - b}{w_2}$
$\implies x_2 = (\dfrac{-w_1}{w_2})x_1 + \dfrac{u-b}{w_2}$

And the questions are:

1) Is the separation line equation above correct?

2) And when `f` is not identity function, is the separation line equation still the same? or different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the output `u` is not related to plotting `x2` against `x1` here, coz `u` is like `z` axis and seeing the separation line is looking perpendicularly to the x1x2 plane, and whatever `u` value is, it's just a dot.

Put `u` as zero for the solving steps in the question.

So the separation line equation is this (with any activation function):

$x_2 = \dfrac{-w_1}{w_2}x_1 + \dfrac{-b}{w_2}$